# Error when starting applications installed via snap

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, snap

I installed flutter based on https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux using:

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

When starting flutter for the first time I get this error, followed by expected output:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
```

Uninstalling (including deleting all flutter files) and reinstalling Flutter made no difference.

How do I troubleshoot this?

I am running Ubuntu 20.10 in VirtualBox 6.1.18

Edit:
The same error occurs when starting Android Studio and libreoffice (also installed via snap)

Comment: Do you really know from where you got `/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so`? Try to move it out the way and retry.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar error. The error seems to be caused by an application, Citrix ICA Client, which I had installed recently. It created a  preloaded file. I renamed the said file. The command I used is:

`sudo mv /etc/ld.so.preload /etc/ld.so.preload.org`

Answer (score 1):

After an update of Ubuntu, the error is gone. I had already done this, but it did not resolve the issue. The last update resolved it. I have not made any other changes.